# 2001 Ford F150 Serious Fuel leak

Tags: ford, fuel-system, leak, fuel-tank

I have a 2001 F150 XLT. I recently had my fule tank replaced because it had a leak. The garage that did the work did say the tank had a hole. Yesterday I picked the truck up. they had put a used tank on it. I would assume they inspected it before installing it but that is not a given. I filled the tank last night and All of the gas with the exception of 1/8 of the tank drained out onto the ground. It was not a pressure spray, it looked more like gas pouring from a faucet and did not change flow with the truck running or off.

I do not believe the leak is on the high pressure side because it continued even when the truck wasnt running. It was pouring out at a amazing rate. It looks like it is some sort of siphoning action that got started when I filled the tank and did not stop until it reached the 1/8 mark. The truck ran fine even while gas was pouring out of it so the high pressure side looks fine.

I had filled it with 5 gallons just after I picked it up and that did not leak out. Any idea where I might look to see what is going on here?

Comment: I would look back to the place which did the work and have them fix it. Ultimately it is there responsibility to ensure the work is done correctly. You've paid for a job which has not been completed, nor accomplished correctly. You'd probably have to remove the tank to figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Maybe not directly relevant, but I have the same truck (model, year, trim) and it had a problem where the rubber hose connecting the tank to the filler neck deteriorated and began to leak. The symptom was that fuel would drip on the ground while fueling (but generally not at other times). Your problem does sound more like a hole in the tank itself, but you may want to check the hoses as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you have a hole in your gas tank.  The fuel is pouring out and running along the frame of the vehicle.

If the fuel pump is not on (ignition is off) no electricity should make it to the fuel pump.  The pressure in the fuel lines would go away and the pump would stop any siphoning action.

Sounds like the shop tried to fix your tank and told you they replaced it.  Liars, take it back or ask for a refund so you can take it to another shop.